# Force a delay on Ajax responses when using the App Engine eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, ajax, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'd like to increase the time it takes the ajax to return in order to test various animations. By default it takes ~3-5ms. Is there a way to force a delay?

I'm using java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll ask the techs to go get you a coffee - if you're getting response times of 3-5ms, you must be camping out in one of our datacenters!

More seriously, assuming you're talking about the time taken to return an HTTP response (I'm not sure where the plugin figures in in all this?), simply use Thread.sleep() to pause execution for a while. Don't use it in production, though, as slow responses will limit your app's scalability!

Comment: is it possible joren is using the local dev server, and thus getting response times that are "too fast"?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the fact I was using the eclipse plugin made it clear I was using the local dev server. :)

I will try Thread.sleep();

Comment: That worked, thanks. I was having issues because I couldn't test any of my jquery animations properly with it returning nigh-instantaneously. :)